# Remove text from placeholder after submit witj JavaScript

Tags: javascript

After refiling the placeholders "Din Navn, Din email, Din besked" with the necessary text and pressing submit "Send besked" button, text inside placeholders stays. I am trying to get the text in placeholders to go back to show the original text (remove the necessary text I put there before), but I am struggling to do it. Is there like a quick function to do that?

Here is the code

```js
const nameInput = document.querySelector("#name");
const email = document.querySelector("#email");
const message = document.querySelector("#message");
const success = document.querySelector("#success");
const errorNodes = document.querySelectorAll(".error");

function validateForm() {

  clearMessage();
  let errorFlag = false;

  if (nameInput.value.length < 1) {
    errorNodes[0].innerText = "Dette felt skal udfyldes";
    nameInput.classList.add("error-border");
    errorFlag = true;
  }
  if (!emailIsValid(email.value)) {
    errorNodes[1].innerText = "Indtast venligst en gyldig email adresse";
    email.classList.add("error-border");
    errorFlag = true;

  }

  if (message.value.length < 1) {
    errorNodes[2].innerText = "Dette felt skal udfyldes";
    message.classList.add("error-border");
    errorFlag = true;

  }

  if (!errorFlag) {
    success.innerText = "Tak, din besked er modtaget";

  } else {
    success.innerText = "Udfyldt venligst felterne"
  }
}

function clearMessage() {
  for (let i = 0; i < errorNodes.length; i++) {
    errorNodes[i].innerText = "";
  }


  nameInput.classList.remove("error-border");
  email.classList.remove("error-border");
  message.classList.remove("error-border");

}


function emailIsValid(email) {
  let pattern = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
  return pattern.test(email);
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay">
  <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); validateForm()" class="formtilgrid">
    <h2>Kontakt Schneider Electric</h2>

    <label for="name">Navn:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Dit navn">
    <small class="error"></small>

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Din email">
    <small class="error"></small>

    <label for="message">Besked:</label>
    <textarea id="message" placeholder="Din besked" rows="6"></textarea>
    <small class="error"></small>

    <div id="center">
      <input type="submit" value="Send besked">
      <p id="success"></p>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I added a `function deleteValue();` to detect for a click on the submit button, once the `function` is triggered, the value of all the original input boxes is set to its original placeholder value after one second from the `setTimeout();`

```js
    const nameInput = document.querySelector("#name");
const email = document.querySelector("#email");
const message = document.querySelector("#message");
const success = document.querySelector("#success");
const errorNodes = document.querySelectorAll(".error");

function validateForm() {

clearMessage();
let errorFlag = false;

if (nameInput.value.length < 1) {
    errorNodes[0].innerText = "Dette felt skal udfyldes";
    nameInput.classList.add("error-border");
    errorFlag = true;
}
if (!emailIsValid(email.value)) {
    errorNodes[1].innerText = "Indtast venligst en gyldig email adresse";
    email.classList.add("error-border");
    errorFlag = true;

}

if (message.value.length < 1) {
    errorNodes[2].innerText = "Dette felt skal udfyldes";
    message.classList.add("error-border");
    errorFlag = true;

}

if (!errorFlag) {
    success.innerText = "Tak, din besked er modtaget";

} else {
    success.innerText = "Udfyldt venligst felterne"
}
}

function clearMessage() {
for (let i = 0; i < errorNodes.length; i++) {
    errorNodes[i].innerText = "";
}


nameInput.classList.remove("error-border");
email.classList.remove("error-border");
message.classList.remove("error-border");

}


function emailIsValid(email) {
let pattern = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
return pattern.test(email);
}

function deleteValue() {

setTimeout(function click(){
    document.getElementById("name").value = "";
document.getElementById("email").value = "";
document.getElementById("message").value = "";

}, 1000)};
```

```html
   

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="overlay">
        <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); validateForm()" class="formtilgrid">
            <h2>Kontakt Schneider Electric</h2>

            <label for="name">Navn:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Dit navn">
            <small class="error"></small>

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Din email">
            <small class="error"></small>

            <label for="message">Besked:</label>
            <textarea id="message" placeholder="Din besked" rows="6"></textarea>
            <small class="error"></small>

            <div id="center">
                <input onclick = "deleteValue();" id = "btn" type="submit" value="Send besked">
                <p id="success"></p>
            </div>
        </form>


    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this worked for you...